# System goes down and back so only make a change in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a system called BOS. The system crashes when 3, 4, 5 or more browsing the system.

The solution is to go into web.config, edit it (any modification, it may even be a blank space) and save it again. And voila, the system returns.

My question is this?
What are the possible causes that?
What may be related to this? Code or Infrastructure?
How to solve?

Comment: It could be anything. We're going to need more information. IIS logs? Windows Event logs? Anything of note happen when you run the site in development? If it works fine with one user but barfs on two or more, it could be static data, threading, race condition or a multitude of other possibilities.

Comment: Watch your resources usage. Editing web.config causes the application to restart (and release all the resorces)

Comment: Also in case you are unaware the web.config file is monitored and when you save it it restarts your web app to pick up the new config. This is why this edit is getting it working again. Its effectively reseting it back to 0 users.

Comment: You could just recycle the application pool to achieve the same results (this is what web.config changes do). What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: What exception messages are you seeing? Can you update the question with more information?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it is only set up to handle around 5 simultaneous requests and it just becomes unresponsive at that point. Try going into your IIS settings and changing that if this is the case, although it's really hard to say with so little information provided. What do you mean by crashes? Internet Explorer crashes? IIS crashes? System just becomes unresponsive and new requests time out?

Comment: What is the IE crashes, he's just carrying po long time without a response.

Answer (score 0):

I would look under the Performance tab in IIS. You might have a maximum connection threshold or bandwidth threshold specified. Every time you modify the web.config file it restarts the application, which is why it starts working again.

If that doesn't work, I would maybe look at something like ANTS Performance Profiler or ANTS Memory Profiler. It will help to identify any bottlenecks that are causing your system to crash. It could be anything, but profiling tools might help to narrow down the culprits.